# Cloudwatch exporter (Prometheus datasource) with difference when getting metrics

Tags: prometheus, grafana, alert, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there any configuration of cloudwatch exporter (Prometheus datasource) where the metrics have the least possible difference compared to Cloudwatch (datasource)?

**Cloudwatch Exporter Config:**

```
region: us-east-1
period_seconds: 30
delay_seconds: 15

metrics:

- aws_dimensions:
  - FunctionName
  - Resource
  aws_metric_name: Invocations
  aws_namespace: AWS/Lambda
  aws_statistics:
  - Sum

- aws_dimensions:
  - FunctionName
  - Resource
  aws_metric_name: Duration
  aws_namespace: AWS/Lambda
  aws_statistics:
  - Average
  - Maximum
  - Minimum

  - aws_dimensions:
  - FunctionName
  - Resource
  aws_metric_name: Errors
  aws_namespace: AWS/Lambda
  aws_statistics:
  - Sum
```

***Last 30 minutes. Using Cloudwatch datasource.***

[image]

***Last 30 minutes. Using prometheus datasource (Cloudwatch Exporter).***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No (but it can be better). You already collect 30sec. aggregated data, so there can be difference. You have also optimistic config (delay 15 sec). I found that metrics in the CloudWatch can have 1-2minutes delay.

I would recommend [Yace](https://github.com/nerdswords/yet-another-cloudwatch-exporter) with this config options:

```
scraping-interval: 60

metrics:
period: 60
length: 300
addCloudwatchTimestamp: true
```

Check Yace doc for all config options and syntax.

Comment: Hello Jan, i use Cloudwatch Exporter and not Yace. 
[Cloudwatch Exporter] (https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter)

Comment: @PabloMarques correct, I recommended Yace